# EditText Android Filter for IP Address ###.###.###.###?

Tags: android, ip-address

I use this filter to validate IP Address

```
localIP.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"));
        InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if (end > start) {
                    String destTxt = dest.toString();
                    String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                    if (!resultingTxt.matches ("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                        for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                            if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        localIP.setFilters(filters);
```

The result allowed is **##.##.##.##**, I want to have a max of **###.###.###.###**.  How do I do this ?

Comment: Why `\d{1,3}`? If you only want to allow clusters of three, `\d{3}` will do the trick.

Comment: thanks sir, i edited in my code  ("^\\d{3}(\\.(\\d{3}(\\.(\\d{3}(\\.(\\d{3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) , but after runs, cannot type in edittext sir

Comment: Oh. Your filter should be set AFTER the `EditText` input is confirmed.

Comment: i change the regex like this  ("^\\d{3}(\\.(\\d{3}(\\.(\\d{3}(\\.(\\d{3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) , but cannot type anyone number in edittext ...

Comment: The filter limits what you can type into the edittext, and since you have to enter three numbers at a time (which isn't possible which you can only enter a single number at once), you can't type anything. You need to set your input check AFTER edittext input is finalized.

Comment: You can try `onTextChangedListener` or add a button that will check the input in its `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 3):

```
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                    android.text.Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if (end > start) {
                    String destTxt = dest.toString();
                    String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart)
                            + source.subSequence(start, end)
                            + destTxt.substring(dend);
                    if (!resultingTxt
                            .matches("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                            if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

        };
        editTxxt.setFilters(filters);
```

> **Or give a look at**

http://kmansoft.com/2011/02/27/an-edittext-for-entering-ip-addresses/

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
   localIP.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    int cursorPosition=0;
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                        localIP.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                        try{
                            cursorPosition= filterText.getSelectionStart();
                            if(editable.length() > 0){

                                String tempIp = "";
                                String newIp = "";
                                String strIp = filterText.getText().toString();
                                String tempParamArr[] = strIp.split("\\.");
                                if(tempParamArr.length > 0){
                                    cursorPosition -= (tempParamArr.length-1);
                                    for(int i = 0; i < tempParamArr.length; i++) {
                                        tempIp += tempParamArr[i];
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    tempIp = strIp;
                                }

                                for(int count = 0; count < tempIp.length(); count++) {
                                    if(count==3 || count==6||count==9||count==12){
                                        newIp += ".";
                                        newIp += tempIp.charAt(count);
                                        cursorPosition++;
                                    }else{
                                        newIp += tempIp.charAt(count);
                                    }
                                }
                                filterText.setText(newIp);
                                if(newIp.length()>cursorPosition)
                                    filterText.setSelection(cursorPosition);
                                else
                                    filterText.setSelection(newIp.length());
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        localIP.addTextChangedListener(this);

                    }
                });
```